# Unity mouse/keyboard shortcuts for "wall" and "expo"

Tags: 10.10, unity, shortcuts

In Unity, is it possible to set up active borders or keyboard shortcuts to enable the "wall" and "expo" views?

Answer (score 1):

*I could be wrong*, but as far as I understand it, this is not currently possible with the mutter version of Unity. I know mutter supports keyboard shortcuts, but I'm not sure how they are configured (GNOME Shell has one for the overlay).

The compiz version will likely have shortcuts though, since compiz natively has keyboard shortcuts enabled for expo etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the current Unity it's not (easily) possible as far as I know, but I assume it will be possible once Unity is a compiz plugin (Compiz already has plugins for this).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can (works for me in 11.04). Since Unity now uses compiz, you can use [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install compizconfig-settings-manager]. It has a searchable interface, is specialized for customizing compiz, and restricts your input to valid options (to reduce mistakes).

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

After installing, you can run it with `ccsm` from the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run window. You can search for plugins by name. "expo" and "wall" will work for you.

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39320/39742#39742) has a screenshot tour for setting up shortcuts for expo and scale.

**Edit:** I just noticed that you tagged your question 10.10. I'm not sure if the above works in Maverick's Unity.